# Javascript check value does not exist

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I can do this...

```
myvalue = "greenapples"

if ( myvalue ) {
    alert ("My Value is " + myvalue )
}
```

But how do I do the opposite?  I want to display an alert if myvalue is not set.

Anyone have an example I can see?

Comment: use `!myvalue`. or better `if(myvalue == undefined)`

Comment: Also, don't create variables without a declaration keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> 1st Way..

```
var myvalue = "greenapples";

if (myvalue === undefined){
alert("My Value Is "+ myvalue)
}
```

> 2nd Way

```
var myvalue = "greenapples";

    if (!myvalue ) {
      alert("My Value is" + myvalue);  // Javascript executes this row
    } else {
      alert("This Is  Already Set");
    }
```

> 3rd Way

**The `typeof` operator will check if the variable is really undefined.**

```
var myvalue = "greenapples";
if (typeof myvalue === 'undefined' || myvalue=== null) {
    // variable is undefined and null then
   alert("My Value Is "+ myvalue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeof myvalue === 'undefined'` and `!myvalue` are two ways of checking if a variable exists.

```
if ( typeof myvalue === 'undefined' ) {
  alert ("variable does not exist");
}

if ( !myvalue ) {
  alert ("variable does not exist");
}
```

Comment: with the second, the first is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways :

one is you can simply use the !(not) operator:

var myvalue = "greenapples";

```
if ( !myvalue ) {
    alert ("My Value not set" );
}
```

OR

You can also an else statement:

```
var myvalue = "greenapples";

if ( myvalue ) {
   }
else{
    alert ("My Value not set " );
}
```

This is saying if the value of a variable is undefined, then do nothing else alert the user. Or if you want in the context of the first code, it says if the value of variable is not undefined, then execute the program

Using the !(not) operator just saves a little bit of control shift in your program.So you will most likely use the !(not) operator